# Not receiving responses from Confluence API when searching for questions in Slack app using the Slack and Confluence APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api, confluence

Rephrasing my question,

Hi, I am working on developing a Slack application that would allow searching for info that is contained in My Confluence space (https://cardknox.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TST/overview)
The node server  is hosted on Glitch. I have added my Glitch URL to the slack API[Glitch URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH9sY.png) [Redirect URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed1pf.png).
I have implemented the integration between Slack and Confluence using the Slack API and Confluence token by following the documentation provided by both platforms, Despite having added all necessary tokens to my server, I am not receiving any responses from the Confluence space when searching for questions in the Slack application. There are no error messages being displayed either. I am seeking assistance in resolving this issue and making the application functional.

Here is my code where I'm utilizing the slack tokens and confluence tokn

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const { SLACK_APP_TOKEN, SLACK_BOT_TOKEN, CONFLUENCE_TOKEN } = process.env;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/slack/interactive-endpoint", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.token || req.body.token !== SLACK_APP_TOKEN) {
    res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
    return;
  }
  // Get the user's question from the Slack request
  try {
    const question = req.body.text;

    // Use the Confluence API to search for the answer to the question
    const options = {
      url: "https://cardknox.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/search",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${CONFLUENCE_TOKEN}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      qs: {
        spaceKey: "TST",
        expand: "body.storage",
        query: question,
      },
    };


  request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).end();
      return;
    }
    const data = JSON.parse(body);
    // Check if an answer was found
    if (data.results.length > 0) {
      // Get the answer from the Confluence API response
      const answers = data.results.map((result) => result.body.storage.value);

      // Use the Slack API to post the answer back to the user
      request.post(
        {
          url: req.body.response_url,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${SLACK_BOT_TOKEN}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          json: {
            text: answers.join("\n"),
          },
        },
        (error, response, body) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).end();
          }
          res.status(200).end();
        }
      );
    } else {
      // If no answer was found, post a message to the user
      request.post(
        {
          url: req.body.response_url,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${SLACK_BOT_TOKEN}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          json: {
            text: "No answer was found for this question, you can check again or contact an admin",
          },
        },
        (error, response, body) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).end();
            return;
          }
          res.status(200).end();
        }
      );
    }
  });
   } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).end();
}
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port 3000!");
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can anyone help me here?

Comment: please provide the response you get from Confluence.